# UITableViewCells text label gets set to a cell when the cell is deleted

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UItableView I can add and delete cells. I can change the `cell.textLabel.text` properties. If i add 13 to my `cell.textLabel.text`...

[image]

and if i delete the TOP cell, that cell's `textLabel` get set to the cell that moved up on the table...

[image]

How can i fix this? I want to be able to delete a cell and have it keep its own `textLabel`. Here is my `cellForRow` method if its needed:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

         addBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         addBtn =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [addBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(220,10,25,55)];
         [addBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [addBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [addBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:addBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(260,10,25,55)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];
     } 
    //cellText.hidden=!self.editing;
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
    cell.tag = indexPath.row; // Important for identifying the cell easily later
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you delete a cell your `UITableView` and all the cells in it get redrawn.  At the time the cell is deleted you need to delete the corresponding object from your data source also (in your case, the array `self.number`) so that the objects in your data source array correspond to the new indexes of the table cells.